# Hide upload Button on Asset Selector Dialog (AssetPortalBrowser.aspx)

Tags: 2010, javascript, jquery, dialog-framework

I am looking to hide the "Upload" button in Asset Selector Dialog and I know Asset Selector Dialog uses Dialog.master in SharePoint. Is there a possibility to attach some custom jQuery/Javascript script which will hide the upload button on Asset Selector Dialog

Note: I don't want to modify OOTB Dialog.master page

The location of Asset Selector Dialog in layouts folder is `test/_layouts/AssetPortalBrowser.aspx`

**Update**: I have the script to hide the upload button but I just want to know how to put it in Dialog.Master? The problem is there exist no delegate control in Dialog.master at the moment which I can use to insert script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried solving the script issue using Custom Action with Location="ScriptLink". It load the javascript on all the site pages and even the dialogs. See I have solved the problem below:

All you need to do is to change the paths accordingly, of course put these custom actions in a feature (Site Collection/Web) :)

```
  <CustomAction Location="ScriptLink" ScriptSrc="~SiteCollection/_layouts/js/jquery-1.5.2.js" Sequence="105" />

  <CustomAction
 Location="ScriptLink"
 ScriptBlock="function loadImageUploaderScript() {       
                      var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];          
                      var script = document.createElement('script');          
                      script.type = 'text/javascript'; 
                      var url = window.location.toString();
                      url = typeof(L_Menu_BaseUrl) != 'undefined' ? L_Menu_BaseUrl : url.substr(0, url.indexOf('/_layouts')); 

                      script.src = url + '/_layouts/js/DefaultUploadOff.js';                          
                      head.appendChild(script);                      
            }   
 _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push('loadImageUploaderScript()');" Sequence="120">
```

DefaultUploadOff.js file will look like as follows:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery("#SiteMgr_Upload_ButtonTable").hide();

});
```

And if your jQuery doesn't work then you can use the following JavaScript code in DefaultUploadoff.js

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("table");
var i = 0;
for (i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
var input = inputs[i];
if (input.id.indexOf('SiteMgr_Upload_ButtonTable') > -1)     
    document.getElementById('SiteMgr_Upload_ButtonTable').style.visibility = "hidden";
}
```

Comment: Oh great man! you are a guru! it is working like a charm :D :D. Many thanks!!!!

Comment: Glad it helped your cause!